# System.InvalidOperationException: 'The LINQ expression could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

So I need to get all the nearly expiry item from database and this are the requirements

First I need to get the Sum of Actual_Delivered based on PO_Summary_Id

```
var getActualDelivered = _context.QC_Receiving
             .GroupBy(x => x.PO_Summary_Id)
             .Select(g => new { PO_Summary_Id = g.Key, ActualDelivered = g.Sum(x => x.Actual_Delivered) });`
```

Next is I will query data from QC_Receiving

```
var receiving = _context.QC_Receiving
        .Where(x => x.Expiry_Date <= DateTime.Now.AddDays(30))
        .GroupBy(x => new
        {
            x.Expiry_Date,
            x.PO_Summary_Id,
            x.Id,
            x.IsNearlyExpire,
            x.ExpiryIsApprove,
            x.TotalReject
        })
        .Select(g => new NearlyExpireDto
        {
            ExpiryDate = g.Key.Expiry_Date.HasValue ? g.Key.Expiry_Date.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") : null,
            Id = g.Key.PO_Summary_Id,
            IsNearlyExpire = g.Key.IsNearlyExpire,
            ExpiryIsApprove = g.Key.ExpiryIsApprove,
            TotalReject = g.Key.TotalReject,
            Days = g.Key.Expiry_Date.HasValue ? (int)Math.Round(g.Key.Expiry_Date.Value.Subtract(DateTime.Now).TotalDays) : 0,
        });
```

This query the data from PO_Summary table:

```
var posummary = _context.POSummary
        .Select(x => new { x.Id, x.PO_Number, x.ItemCode, x.ItemDescription, x.VendorName, x.UOM, x.Ordered, x.IsActive });
```

And this is now the joins statements for the 3 queries:

```
var nearlyExpiryItems = posummary
        .GroupJoin(getActualDelivered,
            posummary => posummary.Id,
            delivered => delivered.PO_Summary_Id,
            (posummary, delivered) => new { posummary, delivered })
        .SelectMany(x => x.delivered.DefaultIfEmpty(),
            (posummary, delivered) => new { posummary.posummary, delivered })
        .GroupJoin(receiving,
            x => x.posummary.Id,
            receiving => receiving.Id,
            (x, receiving) => new { x.posummary, x.delivered, receiving })
        .SelectMany(x => x.receiving.DefaultIfEmpty(),
            (x, receiving) => new { x.posummary, x.delivered, receiving })
        .Where(x => x.receiving == null || x.receiving.ExpiryIsApprove == null)
        .Where(x => x.receiving == null || x.receiving.IsNearlyExpire == true)
        .Select(x => new NearlyExpireDto
        {
            Id = x.posummary.Id,
            PO_Number = x.posummary.PO_Number,
            ItemCode = x.posummary.ItemCode,
            ItemDescription = x.posummary.ItemDescription,
            Supplier = x.posummary.VendorName,
            Uom = x.posummary.UOM,
            QuantityOrdered = x.posummary.Ordered,
            IsActive = x.posummary.IsActive,
            ActualGood = x.receiving.ActualGood,
            ActualRemaining = x.receiving.QuantityOrdered - (x.delivered != null
                ? x.delivered.ActualDelivered - x.receiving.TotalReject
                : x.receiving.TotalReject),
            TotalReject = x.receiving.TotalReject,
            ExpiryDate = x.receiving.ExpiryDate,
            Days = x.receiving.Days,
            IsNearlyExpire = x.receiving.IsNearlyExpire,
            ExpiryIsApprove = x.receiving.ExpiryIsApprove,
            ReceivingId = x.receiving.ReceivingId
        });

return await PagedList<NearlyExpireDto>.CreateAsync(nearlyExpiryItems, userParams.PageNumber, userParams.PageSize);
```

This is my Controller :

```
 [HttpGet]
        [Route("GetAllNearlyExpireWithPagination")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<NearlyExpireDto>>> GetAllNearlyExpireWithPagination([FromQuery] UserParams userParams)
        {
            var expiry = await _unitOfWork.Receives.GetAllNearlyExpireWithPagination(userParams);

            Response.AddPaginationHeader(expiry.CurrentPage, expiry.PageSize, expiry.TotalCount, expiry.TotalPages, expiry.HasNextPage, expiry.HasPreviousPage);

            var nearlyResult = new
            {
                expiry,
                expiry.CurrentPage,
                expiry.PageSize,
                expiry.TotalCount,
                expiry.TotalPages,
                expiry.HasNextPage,
                expiry.HasPreviousPage
            };

            return Ok(nearlyResult);
        }
```

For some reason I'm getting this error. I tried every solution I know but none of them work.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<ImportPOSummary>()
    .LeftJoin(
        inner: DbSet<PO_Receiving>()
            .GroupBy(
                keySelector: p => p.PO_Summary_Id, 
                elementSelector: p => p)
            .Select(e => new { 
                PO_Summary_Id = e.Key, 
                ActualDelivered = e
                    .Sum(x => x.Actual_Delivered)
             }), 
        outerKeySelector: i => i.Id, 
        innerKeySelector: e0 => e0.PO_Summary_Id, 
        resultSelector: (i, e0) => new TransparentIdentifier<ImportPOSummary, <>f__AnonymousType94<int, decimal>>(
            Outer = i, 
            Inner = e0
        ))
    .LeftJoin(
        inner: DbSet<PO_Receiving>()
            .Where(p0 => p0.Expiry_Date <= (Nullable<DateTime>)DateTime.Now.AddDays(30))
            .GroupBy(
                keySelector: p0 => new { 
                    Expiry_Date = p0.Expiry_Date, 
                    PO_Summary_Id = p0.PO_Summary_Id, 
                    Id = p0.Id, 
                    IsNearlyExpire = p0.IsNearlyExpire, 
                    ExpiryIsApprove = p0.ExpiryIsApprove, 
                    TotalReject = p0.TotalReject
                 }, 
                elementSelector: p0 => p0)
            .Select(e1 => new NearlyExpireDto{ 
                ExpiryDate = e1.Key.Expiry_Date.HasValue ? e1.Key.Expiry_Date.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") : null, 
                Id = e1.Key.PO_Summary_Id, 
                IsNearlyExpire = e1.Key.IsNearlyExpire, 
                ExpiryIsApprove = e1.Key.ExpiryIsApprove, 
                TotalReject = e1.Key.TotalReject, 
                Days = e1.Key.Expiry_Date.HasValue ? (int)Math.Round(e1.Key.Expiry_Date.Value.Subtract(DateTime.Now).TotalDays) : 0 
            }
            ), 
        outerKeySelector: ti => ti.Outer.Id, 
        innerKeySelector: e2 => e2.Id, 
        resultSelector: (ti, e2) => new TransparentIdentifier<TransparentIdentifier<ImportPOSummary, <>f__AnonymousType94<int, decimal>>, NearlyExpireDto>(
            Outer = ti, 
            Inner = e2
        ))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.
```

This is my database

[DATABASE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkDz8.png)

I'd like to know why this error coming up and possible solution. I try many solution I know none of worked. I will appreciate your help!

I tried to use LINQ and LAMBDA my first query if raw join query I thought that would be the problem but it's not

Comment: Is there any reason why don you use SQL at database server or some logic with several and more easy linq queries? The error is pretty forward: for some reason that linq sentence can not be translated to SQL. A very point to start is chunk this code in parts and debug it

Comment: You are using `Math.Round` in your LINQ, this will not translate to a SQL statement. Try returning the value without the call to `Math.Round`.

Comment: I do dislike EF Core's error handling here. There will be an `ExpressionVisitor` that replaced some part of the expression tree with a dummy or null value. At that time, the offending expression node could be logged. But it isn't.

Comment: On top of the other comments, I have also noticed that GroupJoin method is not supported by all database providers, either. You could replace that with a Join and DefaultIfEmpty.

Answer (score 0):

The error message seems come from the `var receiving` part . I tested with this part but cannot get the `.HasValue` or `.Value` work.
How about change to this format:

```
var receiving = _context.QC_Receiving
                .Where(x => x.Expiry_Date <= DateTime.Now.AddDays(30))
                .GroupBy(x => new
                {
                    x.Expiry_Date,
                    x.PO_Summary_Id,
                    x.Id,
                    x.IsNearlyExpire,
                    x.ExpiryIsApprove,
                    x.TotalReject
                })
                .Select(g => new NearlyExpireDto
                {
                    ExpiryDate = !(g.Key.Expiry_Date == null) ? g.Key.Expiry_Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") : null,
                    Id = g.Key.PO_Summary_Id,
                    IsNearlyExpire = g.Key.IsNearlyExpire,
                    ExpiryIsApprove = g.Key.ExpiryIsApprove,
                    TotalReject = g.Key.TotalReject,
                    Days = !(g.Key.Expiry_Date == null) ? (int)Math.Round(g.Key.Expiry_Date.Subtract(DateTime.Now).TotalDays) : 0,
                });
                }
```